# What is the fastest way of making random selection from two dependent vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, shuffle

What I am trying to do is to shuffle an existing array (vector). There is a catch here, there are actually two arrays (vectors) that depend on each other.

To be more exact, I have a 2d vector which contains patterns , so each row denotes a single pattern, and then there is another 2d vector which contains the desired output of each pattern.

So it would look like something like this :

```
vector<vector<float>> P{ vector < float > {0, 0},
                         vector < float > {1, 0},
                         vector < float > {0, 1},
                         vector < float > {1, 1} };

vector<vector<float>> T{ vector < float > {0},
                         vector < float > {1},
                         vector < float > {1},
                         vector < float > {0} };
```

Now I need to shuffle the patterns collection, so their individual rows order differ each time we traverse P. again I mean, since P's size() here is 4, and thus we have 4 patterns, and we want to select one at a time till we access all of them.

When all of the patterns are selected one after the other, an epoch is completed, and we need to change the patterns order for the next epoch. We are going to do this for an arbitrary number of times, and each time, these patterns order need to get changed, (e.g. the first time (0,0) is first, followed by (0,1) and (1,0) and finally (1,1), in the second epoch we might be having (1,1) (1,0) (0,0) (0,1) as the patterns).

So when we shuffle the pattern collection, we need to have the targets collection shuffled exactly the same as well. What is fastest way of doing so? There are different ways that ran through my head, such as:

- creating a map out of these two arrays, and map each pattern with the corresponding target, and then shuffle the the patterns collection. Whenever there is a need for a target it can easily be accessed by the map.
- use tuples to create a new list and shuffle the newly created tuple and get going.
- just use a random number between 0 to 3 and pick a number, (a pattern index)  and use that, store the index in an array, which is used to prevent selecting the same index twice in one epoch.

What would you suggest in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want to shuffle indexes:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes{0, 1, 2, 3}; // or initialize with std::iota

std::shuffle(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), my_random_generator);
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to get around the indirection over head of using another vector for accessing an index? or its negligible ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very hard to answer definitively as it lacks a lot of information. And even with all the information needed, a definitive answer would still be very hard to give without *measuring* different options.

The first and most important question is: what is it that you're trying to make fast - generating a new epoch or accessing your data? Answering this question would require knowing the size of the actual data you have, the ways and number of times you access your data in the other code, how is your data modified/generated during runtime, etc.

Here's some general advice though. If you know the size of inner vectors of your `T` and `P` - use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`. This way your inner arrays will be laid out in a single chunk of memory improving cache behaviour. For the same reason, if you can, combine the patterns and outputs into a `std::tuple` or a `std::pair` or a `struct` for that matter and put them all in one array.

Let's assume you can put them into a single vector. Then the regarding the shuffling itself, you can either take the approach with shuffling indices into a static vector or shuffling the vector itself. Shuffling a vector of indices will likely be faster, but you will pay an additional indirection every time you access your pattern-outcome pairs which might make your overall performance way worse than shuffling the vector itself. Your access patterns are of the utmost importance when making the decision - *measure* your options!

If for some reason you absolutely cannot put everything in one vector and additional array of indices is too expensive, consider using this code (note, you need boost and c++14 compiler for this to work, live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a73866374a1ebf5b)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

template <typename... IteratorTypes>
using value_tuple = std::tuple<typename IteratorTypes::value_type...>; 

template <typename... IteratorTypes>
class reference_tuple : public std::tuple<typename IteratorTypes::value_type&...> {
    using std::tuple<typename IteratorTypes::value_type&...>::tuple;
}; 

template<typename... IteratorTypes, size_t... Index>
void swap_impl(reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...> left, reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...> right, std::index_sequence<Index...>)
{
    using std::swap;
    int dummy[] = {(swap(std::get<Index>(left), std::get<Index>(right)), 0)...};
    (void)dummy;
}

template <typename... IteratorTypes>
void swap(reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...> left, reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...> right)
{
    swap_impl(left, right, std::index_sequence_for<IteratorTypes...>{});
}


template <typename... IteratorTypes>
class zip_iter
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
    zip_iter<IteratorTypes...>           // Derived
    , value_tuple<IteratorTypes...>      // Value
    , boost::random_access_traversal_tag
    , reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...>  // Reference
    >
{
public:
    zip_iter() = default;

    explicit zip_iter(IteratorTypes... iters)
        : iterators(iters...)
    {
    }


private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() { increment_impl(std::index_sequence_for<IteratorTypes...>()); }

    template<size_t... Index>
    void increment_impl(std::index_sequence<Index...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = {(++std::get<Index>(iterators), 0)...};
        (void)dummy;
    }

    void decrement() { decrement_impl(std::index_sequence_for<IteratorTypes...>()); }

    template<size_t... Index>
    void decrement_impl(std::index_sequence<Index...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = {(--std::get<Index>(iterators), 0)...};
        (void)dummy;
    }

    template<typename diff_t>
    void advance(diff_t n) { advance_impl(n, std::index_sequence_for<IteratorTypes...>()); }

    template<typename diff_t, size_t... Index>
    void advance_impl(diff_t n, std::index_sequence<Index...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = {(std::advance(std::get<Index>(iterators), n), 0)...};
        (void)dummy;
    }

    bool equal(zip_iter const& other) const
    {
        return std::get<0>(iterators) == std::get<0>(other.iterators);
    }

    auto dereference() const {
        return dereferenceImpl(std::index_sequence_for<IteratorTypes...>{});
    }

    template<std::size_t... Index>
    auto dereferenceImpl(std::index_sequence<Index...>) const
    {
        return reference_tuple<IteratorTypes...>(*std::get<Index>(iterators)...);
    }

    auto distance_to(zip_iter const& r) const
    {
        return std::distance(std::get<0>(iterators), std::get<0>(r.iterators));
    }

    std::tuple<IteratorTypes...> iterators;
};

template<typename... Iterators>
auto make_zip_iter(Iterators... iters)
{
    return zip_iter<Iterators...>(iters...);
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());

    std::vector<int> ints(10);
    std::iota(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    for (auto i : ints) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::vector<int> ints2{ints};

    std::shuffle(make_zip_iter(ints.begin(), ints2.begin()), make_zip_iter(ints.end(), ints2.end()), rng);

    std::cout << "Are equal: " << (ints == ints2) << "\n";

    std::cout << "After: ";
    for (auto i : ints) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I really appreciate the time and the good points made here. 
I am writing a ANN simulator, and usually the epochs are in thousands and millions .  So presenting each pattern to the network has to be fast, or for a large number of patterns and large number of epochs, it would take a huge amount of time to process them and give out an answer. 
And inner sizes of P and T are all dynamically calculated and are not know in advance.

Comment: @Hossein I see. Putting patterns and outcomes into pairs and having one vector seems to me like a more clear design and shuffling such a vector should be pretty much as fast as shuffling ints (assuming c++11 compiler) - I'd start there. One thing is almost sure - avoid the `map` approach - it will likely be slower than any of your other options. The reason I'm saying almost - is that you can never be completely sure about the performance until you measure it.